# In NV D3 horizontal bar chart how to use Json as a data?

Tags: json, d3.js, nvd3.js

Its the source program of nv d3 bar chart program now I separated the hard code of bar chart data, i.e data.json, its not showing chart now.

```
 <script>
   d3.json("Data.json", function (data) {
   var chart;
   nv.addGraph(function() {
   chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
  .x(function(d) { return d.label })
  .y(function(d) { return d.value })
  .margin({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 175})
  .showValues(true)
  .tooltips(false)
  .showControls(false);

   chart.yAxis
  .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

  d3.select('#chart1 svg')
  .datum(data)
  .transition().duration(500)
  .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

 chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e));                   
   });

  return chart;
  });

  });

  </script>
```

Here is the data.json which I separated from source its not working

```
 [
  { 
    "label" : "Group A" ,
    "value" : -1.8746444827653
  } , 
  { 
    "label" : "Group B" ,
    "value" : -8.0961543492239
  } , 
  { 
    "label" : "Group C" ,
    "value" : -0.57072943117674
  } , 
  { 
    "label" : "Group D" ,
    "value" : -2.4174010336624
  } , 
  {
    "label" : "Group E" ,
    "value" : -0.72009071426284
  } , 
  { 
    "label" : "Group F" ,
    "value" : -0.77154485523777
  } , 
  { 
    "label" : "Group G" ,
    "value" : -0.90152097798131
  } , 
  {
    "label" : "Group H" ,
    "value" : -0.91445417330854
  } , 
  { 
    "label" : "Group I" ,
    "value" : -0.055746319141851
  }
]
```

Please help me what went wrong when I separate json

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing any data to the chart except if it was declared before...

```
d3.select('#chart1 svg')
   .datum(long_short_data)
```

This should probably be:

```
d3.select('#chart1 svg')
   .datum(data)
```

if your intention was to load the chart data from the json file...

Comment: I have changed still not working..

Comment: the second error would be the one mentioned by kapep : you need to stick to the same format even if you have a single series, otherwise all the functions that will need to work with that data at the chart level will not work (they will have no data to load for example...)

Answer (score 1):

Stick to the format used in the [example code](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/multiBarHorizontalChart.html), you need to provide *series* of data, even if you only have a single series. Optionally you can also set a colour name for each series.

```
long_short_data = [
  {
    key: 'Series1',   // optional
    color: '#d62728', // optional
    values: [
      {
        "label" : "Group A" ,
        "value" : -1.8746444827653
      } ,
      {
        "label" : "Group B" ,
        "value" : -8.0961543492239
      } 
    /* ... */
  }
];
```

Comment: Guys i have tried in the default format also no use , is there anyone who did separate the json file any example available? All i need is to get data from sql db accordingly drawing the chart. tell me friends in which format i need to get data from sql db.

Comment: @Purushoth If you are sure the `data` argument of the `d3.json` function is in the format shown above (use console to verify) then I'm sure it's not a _json file_ problem. Look at the js console log if there are any errors.